# How to get most recent data from DynamoDB for each primary partition key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in dynamodb. It stores account stats. It's possible that the account stats will be updated several times per day. So table records may look like:

```
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| account_id | record_id    | views | stars |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 3          | 2019/03/16/1 | 29    | 3     |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 2          | 2019/03/16/2 | 130   | 21    |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 1          | 2019/03/16/3 | 12    | 2     |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 2          | 2019/03/16/1 | 57    | 12    |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 1          | 2019/03/16/2 | 8     | 2     |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 1          | 2019/03/16/1 | 3     | 0     |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
```

`account_id` is a primary partition key.
`record_id` is a primary sort key

How I can get only latest records for each of the `account_id`s? So from the example above I expect to get:

```
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| account_id | record_id    | views | stars |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 3          | 2019/03/16/1 | 29    | 3     |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 2          | 2019/03/16/2 | 130   | 21    |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 1          | 2019/03/16/3 | 12    | 2     |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
```

This data is convenient to use for a reporting purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done quite efficiently if you know the list of `account_id`s that you have stored in the table.

In that case, all you need to do is to query primary keys, one by one, sorting values using `ScanIndexForward=False` and limiting the result to 1 item using `Limit=1`.

Here is code in python

```
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

account_ids = ['1', '2', '3']
results = []

for aid in account_ids:
    result = client.query(
        TableName='test-table',
        KeyConditionExpression="#aid = :aid",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            '#aid': 'account_id'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':aid': {
                'N': aid
            }
        },
        ScanIndexForward=False,
        Limit=1,
    )
    results.append(result['Items'])

print(json.dumps(results, indent=2))
```

Comment: Using account_id in the query (in KeyConditionExpression) with ScanIndexForward=False & Limit=1 though is the solution, I see an issue with performance. i.e., when the table grows over time, the query reads everything matching the primary-key and then filtering to get the latest record, which may hit the RCU limit in dynamodb. Anybody faced this/ handled it?

Comment: @nbs that isn't what happens. The DynamoDB query doesn't read every item that matches the primary key. It maintains an index on pk+sk. If you query on pk with ScanIndexForward=False and Limit=1 it goes directly to the last item in the sort order and fetches it. There is no fetching of additional items and there is no filtering.

Answer (score 4):

Items with the same partition key are stored in the same partition and are ordered by their sort key. So, if you query the items in reverse and set a limit of 1, you will get the item with the required `account_id` and the maximum `record_id`.

So, issue a query on the relevant `account_id` but specify `Limit=1` and `ScanIndexForward=False` (or `Reverse=True` depending on which SDK/API you use).