# How to get most recent data from DynamoDB for each primary partition key in PartiQL

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, partiql

inspired from this [How to get most recent data from DynamoDB for each primary partition key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56136226/how-to-get-most-recent-data-from-dynamodb-for-each-primary-partition-key)

I have a table in dynamodb. It stores account stats. It's possible that the account stats will be updated several times per day. So table records may look like:

+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| account_id | record_id    | views | stars |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 3          | 2019/03/16/1 | 29    | 3     |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 2          | 2019/03/16/2 | 130   | 21    |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 1          | 2019/03/16/3 | 12    | 2     |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 2          | 2019/03/16/1 | 57    | 12    |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 1          | 2019/03/16/2 | 8     | 2     |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 1          | 2019/03/16/1 | 3     | 0     |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
account_id is a primary partition key. record_id is a primary sort key

How I can get only latest records for each of the account_ids? So from the example above I expect to get:

+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| account_id | record_id    | views | stars |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 3          | 2019/03/16/1 | 29    | 3     |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 2          | 2019/03/16/2 | 130   | 21    |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| 1          | 2019/03/16/3 | 12    | 2     |
+------------+--------------+-------+-------+
This data is convenient to use for a reporting purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the following PartiQL query for each account_id:

```sql
SELECT * FROM <Table> WHERE account_id='3' AND record_id > '2021/11' ORDER BY record_id DESC
```

PartiQL has no `LIMIT` keyword, so will return all matching records.
You can reduce overfetching by constraining the `record_id` date to the extent possible.  If only the current date is of interest, for example, the sort key expression would be `record_id > 2021/12/01`.

As in the referenced example, you must execute one query for each `account_id` of interest.  [Batching operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.multiplestatements.batching.html) are supported.